# How to create array of .gif files based on form checkboxes

Tags: php

**Objective:** to have a form of checkbox categories users can choose from that generates an array of ALL .gif files from chosen directories.

My Guess to go about this problem would be to create an array of directories to pass into a glob() function. But my problem is properly formatting the directory arguments. Or perhaps there is a more efficient way to accomplish this.

**Sample Code:**

```
<form method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="category_1" value="true">
  <input type="checkbox" name="category_2" value="true">
  <input type="checkbox" name="category_3" value="true">
  <input type="checkbox" name="category_4" value="true">
  <input type="checkbox" name="category_5" value="true">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
$dir = [];  //INITIALIZE DIR - ONLY REFERENCED IN IF STATEMENTS
if(isset($_GET['category_1'])){
  $dir[] = "gif/category_1/*.gif"
}
if(isset($_GET['category_2'])){
  $dir[] = "gif/category_2/*.gif"
}
if(isset($_GET['category_3'])){
  $dir[] = "gif/category_3/*.gif"
}
if(isset($_GET['category_4'])){
  $dir[] = "gif/category_4/*.gif"
}
if(isset($_GET['category_5'])){
  $dir[] = "gif/category_5/*.gif"
}

$images = glob(foreach($dir as $path){echo $path}, GLOB_BRACE)
?>
```

The Problem here is that multiple glob arguments must be separated by commas so I could append a comma to the echo $dir[] loop, but it would still leave a comma at the end which is invalid.

**Example:**

```
<?php echo $path.','; // this would leave comma at end. ?>
```

Am I on the right track? Or is there a better way to do this.
Thanks in advance for everyone's help!

Comment: what about: `implode(',', $dir);`

Comment: Yes, thanks! I didn't know about implode()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) will return concatenated string with ',' without leaving trailing comma and avoid `foreach` loop

```
$images = glob(implode(',', $dir), GLOB_BRACE)
```

Comment: When I substitue what I had for this solution everyone proposed, I get an error stating  variable dir is undefined..

Comment: The error message goes away when I submit form, but I have the get variables wrapped in isset() to prevent it. Maybe I need some kind of conditional for $images = glob(implode(',', $dir), GLOB_BRACE)?

Comment: Didn't understand what you need. Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: The error was that $dir was never initialized because all references to it were located in if statements. So adding $dir = [] into the code fixed the problem. Thanks for the help! Just a little oversight by me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem you can use implode.

```
$images = glob(implode(",", $dir), GLOB_BRACE)
```

Implode will output the array items comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

You  can use [implode()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp) function for this. 
Like below.

```
$images = glob(implode(",", $dir), GLOB_BRACE);
```